# Custom attribute options value in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add a custom column in “**Attribute option**” in “**Manage Attribute Options**” menu in admin. Like “value” column beside the position column in admin.

**What I have done ...**

1. created a new filed in ”eav_attribute_option” table named “value” beside “sort_order” filed in database.
2. changed ”magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\attribute\options.phtml” this file to show the “Value” column beside the “Position” column.
3. changed ”getOptionValues()” method in this file ”magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit\Options\Abstract.php” to get data for my custom “value” column from database and show in admin side. It shows the default value of db in admin form.

*** But when I want to save from admin panel the data doesn't save in db. Can anybody help which file I have to change to save the data of “Value” field into db? Can anybody please give any solution, which file or where have to change ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, go to:

- magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Resource\Entity\Attribute.php
- copy to local of course
- find "protected function _saveOption"
- copy how "sort_order" was being saved or inserted, so look on "$data" array.

i'm actually trying to figure this functionality for a while and you've gave the hints by giving which files needs to be modified, so thank you  :)